# How to manage a global config variable in react/redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The API I'm working with requires me to get a new key every x hours. I would like to be able to store the key in a global state of sorts. However, here is where I'm stuck. I have lots of parts in my app where I have components that do API calls, but doing the whole Redux

```
function blah() {
axios.get('url')
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({type: "THING_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
  })
```

pattern would be overkill. If I were to do it this way, I would just store the api key with redux and use it from there. However, I just want to do that `axios.get()` within the component itself (some of the components are deeeeeply nested, so passing the api key through all the components all the way down from the top component seems bad). How can I manage this api key from anywhere in my app without having to wrap everything in Redux?

Comment: Why can't you just have a global variable? It's not ideal, especially in a Redux system, but sometimes it's the easiest approach.

Comment: You can make your store global and then ask store.getState(), but in this case it will not refresh your components when data will be changed. The reason for what you shout pass the data through whole tree is to inform the right components that somethig has changed.

Anothr option is the Context(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) but it is also for something else.